# Is it possible to left-muliply with Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Generally in the Lagrange method, you adjoin your model equations $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$ to an Objective function $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{x})$, to find the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda) = \mathcal{J}(\mathbf{x}) +\lambda^{\top}\mathbf{g}
$$ 
In my setting however, I am dealing with an interative model, and if I use this model I do not get the correct equations. I did notice that when I would write the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda) = \mathbf{g}^{\top}\lambda
$$
That it does give me the correct equations. 
However, is this mathematically correct? I can't find it in literature anywhere

Cheers,
Wessel

Comment: `if I use this model I do not get the correct equations` You're probably making an error, such as messing up the calculation of the derivative when transposes are involved. It might be worth making a new post showing *exactly* how you are computing and asking where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are (column) vectors, then

$$\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}= \mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{w}$$

as can be checked by writing out what the terms mean in terms of components.  Since they're equal, you can use them interchangeably.